# Query string parameter names for SEO

Tags: seo

If I have a website like:

```
google.com/index.html?c=123123&p=shoes
```

Will it be better for SEO to have it as:

```
google.com/index.html?code=123123&footwear=shoes
```

I mean, does giving useful names to query string parameters help SEO?

Answer (score 3):

Yes query string could help Google to understand the meaning of the page.

What is important with query string that you display unique content when changing the value of a parameter.

Example:

```
google.com/index.html?code=123123&footwear=shoes

google.com/index.html?code=123123&footwear=shoesB
```

If in this case you display the same content you can occur in duplicated issues.
(You can also use canonical URL)

The best would be re-write the the string as URL friendly like

```
google.com/footwear/shoes/name-product-ID
```

A unique URL for each product.

Here some useful resource of duplicate issue

http://www.seomoz.org/learn-seo/duplicate-content

Hope can help