# Disallow double or junk wildcard subdomains in htaccess mod rewrite for SEO

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have wildcard subdomains enabled on my domain. I use this so that I can rewrite urls like `es.domain.com` to `domain.com/page.php?lang=es` and display to the user the local language version of page.php.

The one potential problem I see with allowing wildcard subdomains is that people can link to `www.es.domain.com` or even `anything.they.like.domain.com` and it will display a perfectly working clone of the website. I presume this 'duplicate content' is bad for SEO.

Can anyone come up with a RewriteRule which detects subdomains of more than 2 letters (www. excluded of course) and 301 redirects offending urls to the clean base `domain.com`? I'm having trouble when I consider domains like `domain.co.uk` which already look like they are on a subdomain.

As a side note, are there any similar implications for SEO on the opposite side of the url, with query parameters? For example, `domain.com?param=anything-I-like` will surely show a duplicate page. How does Google handle this content?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the rewrite rule I'm using currently. If I wanted to clean up bad urls with PHP, I'd need to modify this to catch all subdomains. i need to do this generically (without specifying domain.com) as it's going to be used on a CMS. Any suggestions?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\.
RewriteRule p/(.*) page.php?p=$1&lang=%1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all for the info & replies on this. The solution I've found is to write a more generic .htaccess rule to catch ***all*** subdomains and forward them to PHP for processing. PHP then checks if the subdomain is valid and if not, 301 redirects the visitor to the root domain. This way if someone links to blah.blah.domain.com, Search engines should see that as a link to just domain.com. I'm only using language subdomains on my site but it should work for any subdomains you want to use.

**Here's the htaccess rewrite:**

The regex works by finding the last instance of more than 3 domain-name-valid characters, followed by a dot, followed by any other string. The idea is that it finds the domain name in the url, then captures everything before it. Obviously this wont work for domains which are shorter than 3 characters.

```
#All sub domains are redirected to p.php for processing:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.[a-z0-9\-]{3,}\..*
RewriteRule (.*) p.php?subdom=%1 [L]
```

**Here's the PHP:**

```
function redirect301($page='/'){
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); 
    header("Location:{$page}");
    exit(); 
}

$subdom = $_REQUEST['subdomain']; //you should sanitise this if using this script!
$defaultLang = 'en';
$alternateLangs = "de|es"; //list of allowed subdomains
$alternateLangs = explode('|',$alternateLangs);

if(!empty($subdom) && $subdom!= 'www'){
    if( !in_array($subdom,$alternateLangs) ) redirect301(); //redirect to homepage
    $ISOlangCode = $subdom; // en,es,de,etc - capture code for use later
}
if($defaultLang && $ISOlangCode == $defaultLang) redirect301(); //disallow subdomain for default language (redirect to homepage)
```

Hopefully this helps someone out.

Answer (score 1):

I honestly can't speak to fixing your actual issue, but I can confirm that anything.I.want.domain.com is really, REALLY bad for SEO. I've got two years' experience in the field and I'm currently working on a project cleaning up links for our main U.S. site. A couple of the biggest problems have come from sites just like you described where there were around 100 *.domain.com. The biggest issue is the effect of this problem with trust flow, it basically sends a link's trust rating to 0 and tells Google that, not only should this link be disregarded, the domain it came from and links to should be investigated for potential spammy-ness.

As to your final question on implications:

Query parameters can be just as helpful or detrimental as any other URL structure, so you want to be careful with those, as well. If you've got different language versions of your site, be sure to have one (especially if you don't have entirely unique content) as the rel-canonical page. The thing is, linking structure is important to search engines, but not overly so. It's one of many metrics. I'd be far more concerned about the subdomains. If you happen to be able to sneak in some small, basic keywords that help describe the page in with your query vars, it could help a bit. I would, however, highly suggest that you have a three or four tiered structure to your site, supported in the URLS.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459501/query-string-parameter-names-for-seo)

Google tends to like: domain.com/landingpage/category/subcategory?somevars=44

Going more than three deep spreads you too thin and less than that makes the site too bulky to navigate. I believe it's covered somewhat here if you've never seen it: http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo

[Search Engine Journal](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/)

[Single Grain](http://www.singlegrain.com/blog/) and

[Moz](http://moz.com/blog)

can answer a lot of your SEO questions and tools like:

[Majestic](http://www.majesticseo.com/)

[Soolve](http://www.soovle.com/)

[Mozcast](http://mozcast.com/)

[SERPMetrics Flux](http://serpmetrics.com/flux/)

can help a lot, too. Try doing a little reading and see if you can decide a good scheme for your links.

Again, sorry, I don't know really any Apache, but hopefully that'll help!

Comment: Thanks Drew - interesting reading in there. I didn't realise wildcard subdomains caused such a shit storm!

Comment: They can. They won't always, but if someone is using your site the way we've seen happen to some other webmasters, it can definitely degrade your performance in the SERPs and negatively impact anyone you link to. I, of course, overstated the gravity of the situation a bit, links are only one of a lot of metrics. If you've got a brain cell and a bit of experience programming, I'd look into Google's original research paper, too, and try thinking about the way their algorithm has evolved since then. ;) http://infolab.stanford.edu/~backrub/google.html

Comment: Wow, its cool to see such a relic from baby Google! In light of compounding issues with these redirects, I'm actually considering abandoning this wildcard thing now and figuring out a way to programatically create only the subdomains I need. it will likely melt my head but it would just make everything cleaner & safer I think. Thanks again for the info Drew.

Comment: Yep, I swear that enhanced my abilities and understanding 10 fold, though I'm more of a programmer and web designer by trade than a marketing / SEO person. That seems like a fine solution as long as no one can create the subdomains but you. Best of luck with the redesign!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have a rewrite rule that takes anything in front of `domain.com` and puts it into the `lang` parameter.  Rather than having a rewrite rule to do the redirecting, have your `page.php` script examine the lang parameter and issue a redirect for invalid values.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking something similar. I think I might need a more robust rewriteRule in that case tho. The one I'm using only redirects 2 letter subdomains. I'll post it above and maybe someone will suggest a better version which will catch any subdomain